# add Javascript in ionic html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to execute Javascript in a ionic modal (HTML) page. It may sound weird, because normally it think you put JS code into a JS file and use data binding to work with js in html, right? But in this case i only can change this specific html file.. So this is what i tried:

```
<div class="modal">

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-secondary">


    <h1 class="title">TEST-TITLE</h1>
    <button class="button button-clear button-dark" ng-click="modal.hide()"><i class="icon ion-close"></i></button>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content class="has-header" delegate-handle="TEST">
    <div class="list card">

      <div class="item item-body" ng-App="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <img src="pathToFile.jpg" class="full-image">
        <p>
           TEXT
        </p>

        <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="testFunction()">
          TEST-BUTTON
        </button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </ion-content>
</div>


<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.testFunction = function () {

            $scope.firstName = "John";
            $scope.lastName = "Doe";
            alert($scope.firstName);
        };
    });
</script>
```

But i cannot run the function "testFunction()" after clicking on TEST-BUTTON. Does anyone know what to do?

Update: 
This is how the modal is called in the extended js file:

```
   // Fetch the modal and store it in scope
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('pathToModal', {
  scope: $scope,
  animation: 'slide-in-up'
}).then(function (modal) {
  $scope.modal = modal;
});
```

Comment: change `ng-App` to `ng-app`

Comment: Thx! Bu it's still not working...

Comment: So you are calling this modal from other angular js code? Then why do you have another `ng-app` in your modal?

Comment: like i said, i cannot change the extended js file. My only goal is to exec code in the html-modal! I thought it could work with defining a new controller in a new app to do this.. Other ideas?

Comment: I mean that your code already runs in angular context. Somewhere else there probably is `ng-app` defined. Use that module instead of creating a new one: `angular.module("theModuleName").controller("myCtrl", ..)` and remove your `ng-app` attribute in your modal.

Comment: you can add in .ts file and declare var $: any;  globally